# Is it possible to set timestamp with 30 minute from current_timestamp default value column when loading CSV?

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, psycopg2

I have a timestamp field `insert_time` that is defined to be automatically updated with the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP value.

It works fine if I define the value below while importing civ to PostgresDB.

1. Give timestamp column as `now()` function in csv
2. Manually enter timestamp like `2013-08-08` in the csv

As current condition I would like to insert timestamp with 30 minutes from the current_timestamp, so I simply put

`NOW()-INTERVAL'30 MINUTES'`, and the system returns me error with statements below.

> InvalidDatetimeFormat: invalid input syntax for type timestamp:
> "(NOW() - INTERVAL '30 MINUTES')"
> CONTEXT:  COPY trade, line 1, column insert_time: "(NOW() - INTERVAL '30 MINUTES')".

Is there any workaround I can simply use to import data without changing code base to do so?

[DB Table properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ei4Q1.jpg)

Sample of CSV:

```
c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821bdf,2290736458974872576,c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821bdf,10,40000000,BTC,2290736449804431425,2022030100,1646106066455,10,40000000,BTC,8,4000000000,USDT,c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821bde,8,4000000000,USDT,2290736443845317312,27729472,"19447008-1",A,BTC_USDT,BUY,1646106066455,2,600000,6,1000000,1646106066455,sample_trade,sample_trade,NOW() - INTERVAL '30 MINUTE'
c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821bd2,2290735086865954176,c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821bd2,10,40000000,ETH,2290735071284965826,2022030100,1646106025563,10,40000000,ETH,8,4000000000,USDT,c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821bde,8,4000000000,USDT,2290735065371963840,27727648,"19445792-0",A,ETH_USDT,BUY,1646106025563,2,1000000,6,1000000,1646106025563,sample_trade,sample_trade,NOW() - INTERVAL '30 MINUTE'
c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821bd3,2290728307695304704,c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821bd3,10,40000000,VET,2290728283028522497,2022030100,1646105823528,10,40000000,VET,8,4000000000,USDT,c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821bde,8,4000000000,USDT,2290728277231940960,27725824,"19444576-1",A,VET_USDT,BUY,1646105823528,2,1000000,6,1000000,1646105823528,sample_trade,sample_trade,NOW() - INTERVAL '30 MINUTE'
c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821bd4,2290722365598402272,c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821bd4,10,40000000,LUNA,2290722340448397249,2022030100,1646105646440,10,40000000,LUNA,8,4000000000,USDT,c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821bde,8,4000000000,USDT,2290722334488401536,27724000,"19443360-8",A,LUNA_USDT,BUY,1646105646440,2,1000000,6,1000000,1646105646440,sample_trade,sample_trade,NOW() - INTERVAL '30 MINUTE'
c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821bd5,2290589190301423232,c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821bd5,10,74800000,ADA,2290589095070535169,2022030100,1646101677507,10,74800000,ADA,8,4000000000,USDT,c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821bde,8,4000000000,USDT,2290589120065645888,22440128,"16738528-1",A,ADA_USDT,SELL,1646101677507,2,600000,6,1870000,1646101677507,sample_trade,sample_trade,NOW() - INTERVAL '30 MINUTE'
c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821bd6,2290584188362083520,c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821bd6,10,40000000,MANA,2290584186822704929,2022030100,1646101528437,10,40000000,MANA,8,4000000000,USDT,c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821bde,8,4000000000,USDT,2290584180756419392,22409120,"16708128-0",A,MANA_USDT,BUY,1646101528437,2,600000,6,1000000,1646101528437,sample_trade,sample_trade,NOW() - INTERVAL '30 MINUTE'
c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821bd7,2290582829397526912,c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821bd7,10,40000000,BUSD,2290582809255269282,2022030100,1646101487937,10,40000000,BUSD,8,4000000000,USDT,c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821bde,8,4000000000,USDT,2290582803356323808,22407296,"16706912-0",A,BUSD_USDT,BUY,1646101487937,2,1000000,6,1000000,1646101487937,sample_trade,sample_trade,NOW() - INTERVAL '30 MINUTE'
c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821bd8,2290579188400153888,c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821bd8,10,40000000,AAVE,2290579149684042434,2022030100,1646101379427,10,40000000,AAVE,8,4000000000,USDT,c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821bde,8,4000000000,USDT,2290579143738594816,22405472,"16705696-0",A,AAVE_USDT,BUY,1646101379427,2,1000000,6,1000000,1646101379427,sample_trade,sample_trade,NOW() - INTERVAL '30 MINUTE'
c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821bd9,2290576756852686496,c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821bd9,10,40000000,ETH,2290576726140179970,2022030100,1646101306961,10,40000000,ETH,8,4000000000,USDT,c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821bde,8,4000000000,CRO,2290576720287178368,22403648,"16704480-0",A,ETH_CRO,BUY,1646101306961,2,1000000,6,1000000,1646101306961,sample_trade,sample_trade,NOW() - INTERVAL '30 MINUTE'
c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821aa1,2290574614735494369,c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821aa1,10,40000000,MANA,2290574580787974626,2022030100,1646101243121,10,40000000,MANA,8,4000000000,USDT,c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821bde,8,4488000000,CRO,2290574606968299904,22401216,"16703072-1",A,MANA_CRO,SELL,1646101243121,2,600000,6,1870000,1646101243121,sample_trade,sample_trade,NOW() - INTERVAL '30 MINUTE'
```

Data import source code

```
@keyword("Import trade data to db")
def import_trade_data():
    _connection = init_database_connection()
    _nts_connection = init_nts_database_connection()

print(f'Connecting to {pg_host}:{pg_port} db {pg_db} with user {pg_user}')
import_file = f'{os.getcwd()}/data/import_trade_data.table'

cur = _connection.cursor()

if os.path.isfile(import_file):
    import_file1 = open(import_file, 'r')
    trade_tables = import_file1.readlines()

print('import data')
# import data
for data in trade_tables:
    data = str.rstrip(data)
    table_file = f'{os.getcwd()}/data/trade.csv'
    if os.path.isfile(table_file):
        print(f'loading {table_file}')
        f = open(table_file)
        cur.copy_from(file=f, table=data, sep=',')
        _connection.commit()
    else:
        print(f'Expected table file {table_file} not found')
write_to_console(f'Data is imported: {cur.rowcount}')

print('update data')

cur.execute(f"update exchange_order set source_sequence = 0 where status in ('ACTIVE', 'PENDING');")
cur.execute(f'update balance set source_sequence = 0 where source_sequence != 0;')
cur.execute(f'update event_source_sequence set last_sequence = 0;')
cur.execute(f'update event_source_sequence set related_id = 0;')
_connection.commit()
```

Comment: So which mean the expression is actually no workable above?

Comment: ah, I get it. Just tried the above syntax, it also return me the same error..

Comment: InvalidDatetimeFormat: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE"
CONTEXT:  COPY trade, line 1, column insert_time: "NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE"

Comment: Nothing to do with mysql , mysql tag removed. How are you loading? Please publish statement and sample csv

Comment: Have added the sample of CSV and source code above

Comment: @RiggsFolly, there is nothing wrong with the syntax as this is `psycopg2` in other words Postgres and what you showed is for `MySQL`.

Comment: Your CSV has `NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE` which is not valid. It would need to be `NOW() - INTERVAL '30 MINUTE'`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Yes you are correct, A random spamming of tags caused the confusion

Answer (score 0):

No.  COPY works with data, not with expressions.  'now()' is an special case exception to that, but it does not extend to other expressions.

Comment: seem you are correct, no matter what expression I put the DB not allow me import value like this... best way to solve it may be by script